# Thread and super keyword

Tags: java, multithreading

The following code will output **Program A**. Kindly explain it w.r.t `super.run();`.

```
class RunnableA implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Program A");
    }
}

class MyThread extends Thread{
    MyThread(Runnable r){
        //set as a target
        super(r);
    }
    public void run(){
        //System.out.println("MyThread");
        super.run();
    }
}

class Demo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        RunnableA a1=new RunnableA();
        //a1.start(); //Illegal
        new MyThread(a1).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add more description of what you are exactly looking for. Your question is very unclear and will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

`super.run();` means that `MyThread`'s `run()` method executes `Thread`'s `run()` method (which calls the `run()` method of the `Runnable` instance that was passed to the constructor).

Therefore `new MyThread(a1).start();` executes `RunnableA`'s `run()` method and prints `"Program A"`.

In this example `MyThread` is quite useless, as it doesn't add any functionality to `Thread`. You can replace your main method with :

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    RunnableA a1=new RunnableA();
    new Thread(a1).start();
}
```

and get the same behavior.